# Is neighborhoods on a subspace is the same as the intersection of neighborhoods and the subspace?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $(\Omega,\tau)$ be a topological space and $A$ is subset of $\Omega$, the relative topology(subspace) is $(A,\tau_A)$, $x$ any point of $A$. Question is

$$\mathcal{N}_{\tau_A}(x)= \{N\cap A:N\in \mathcal{N}_\tau (x)\}$$

holds or not?

Where $\mathcal{N}_\tau (x)$ denoted all the neighborhoods of $x$ in $\tau$

Comment: Every open set of the relative topology is of the form $U \cap A$, for some $U$ in τ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that holds.

Let $\,x\in A.\,$ If $\,N\,$ is a neighborhood of $\,x\,$ in $\Omega$, then there exists an open set $\,U\,$ of $\,\Omega\,$ such that $\,x\in U \subseteq N$, and therefore

$$ x\in U\cap A\;\subseteq\; N\cap A, $$

so $\,N\cap A\,$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $\,A$, being $\,U\cap A\,$ an open set of $\,A\,$ by definition.

Conversely, if $\,N'\,$ is a neighborhood of $\,x\,$ in $\,A$, there exists an open set $\,U'\,$ of $\,A\,$ such that

$$\,x\in U'=U\cap A\subseteq N'$$

for some open set $\,U\,$ of $\,\Omega$. Now, if we put

$$ N:= N'\cup U, $$

we obtain

$$ N\cap A = \big(N'\cup U\big)\cap A = \big(N'\cap A\big) \cup \big(U\cap A\big) = N'\cup U' = N', $$

and we are done, since $\,N\,$ is a neighborhood of $\,x\,$ in $\Omega\,$ because $\,N\supseteq U\ni x\,$ and $\,U\,$ is open in $\,\Omega$.